# How to implement multi select dropdown list in Blazor application?

Tags: blazor, razor-pages

I am trying to implement a dropdown list with checkboxes which allows multiple selections. The multiple selections will be displayed as comma separated list upon selection. Is there any inbuilt control that can be used in razor page. I looked at html select control, MatCheckBox control but they dont seem to have this appearance.
Thanks for any suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've used **Radzen Components** in my app, they generally work well. And they are free.

They have a dropdown with multiple select:

https://blazor.radzen.com/dropdown-multiple